# iPhone: Set value of current textField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am calling an action from textFieldDidBeginEditing as follows:

```
[dotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and specifiying my action as:

```
- (void) actionButton:(id)sender {
textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"APPROVED"];
}
```

Simple question with hopefully a simple answer....

textField.text refers to the field named textField  but how do I update the current field that textFieldDidBeginEditing is acting on at the time??  i.e  can I set a variable to retrieve the current fieldname?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your code to look like code. put 4 spaces before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether or not the textField the label of your interest.
An example:

```
if (textField == self.firstLabel){
  //do something
}
else if (textField == self.secondLabel){
  //do other something
}
```

The textField variable that is passed from the delegate method is the one that you should handle.

Tell me if it works. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty new to this (like a few weeks old!) can you through a bit of sample code at me to explain a little more what you mean by 'cast it to UITextField"?

Comment: Insert this line of code before yours in -actionButton: and it should work automagically.

Comment: Sorry...Don't get ye Costique..what line of code, where?  I like automagically...that would be super :)

Comment: Hoang...the sender here is actually UIButton so it's causing debug errors now